# Would you use VersionOne also as issue-tracking system (aka BugZilla)

Tags: methodology, issue-tracking, versionone, agile-project-management

Within our Agile / Scrum team there is the idea to start using [VersionOne](http://www.versionone.com/) as the project planning tool. My question is, can it also handle the issues (defects; new feature requests; improvements; patches) that come in? Meaning can it also replace a issue-tracking system like [BugZilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/)? In a issue tracking system, many people (developers but also customers (/customer support)) typically enter issues. Then these issues go through a work flow cycle (new; in-progress; solved; closed, etc). Also the affects version and fix version (multiple - branches).

Can this be done in VersionOne, out off the box? Or would some customisation be needed? Or would you recommend to keep an other issue tracking system in the background (like BugZilla, [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/), etc)?

Looking forward to read the experiences of others.

Regards, Tjeerd

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VersionOne has these features.

I can't tell you what it looks like out of the box because I use a centrally managed VersionOne server. My guess is that it's a fairly standard implementation.

VersionOne is a very powerful tool but it takes a certain amount of administration to set teams and iterations up properly. If you're a small team, it might do more than you need, and like most software tools it can slow down the planning and review processes.

It's a reasonable defect tracking system, however I find its search facilities a bit clunky.

A number of StackOverflow users have highly recommended it. If you are planning a remote, corporate level implementation, then I strongly recommend that you run some realistic benchmarks (but this is only good practice, right?) to ensure that your remote users will receive an acceptable level of service. If it's a local server for a small number of teams then I wouldn't expect any problems.

By the way, have you considered FogBugz? It has a very nice user experience and integrates well with other systems.

Comment: Small company, few teams (4-6) (from each 4 to 12 people) (so benchmarking would/should be overkill).

FogBugz, not yet, let me do so. Thanks for the reply!